# Return false ignored by onsubmit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I've spent hour working on this so I'm going to be frustrated when it turns out it's just a single quote in the wrong place or something.

I'm making a basic HTML page to test a basic validate form input.  If I drop the return false at the start of the validateForm() function, it works as expected.   However, if it's within the validation loop (as below) it doesn't work and the form submits.  (hello.php just outputs hello world).

All of the diagnostic alerts that are in here run as expected... including the one right before the return-false. (when I leave an input blank).

I feel like I'm missing something very obvious, but can't figure out what it is.

```
<?php 
echo <<<END
<html>
 <head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <title>Test</title>

   <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input").focus(function(){
    $(this).css("background-color","#cccccc");
  });
  $("input").blur(function(){
        $(this).css("background-color","#ffffff");
  });
});

function validateForm() {
    alert("Validating");    
    $("form[name=queryForm]").find(":input[type=text]").each(function() {
        alert("Checking " + $(this).attr('name'));
        if($(this).val()==null || $(this).val()=="") {
            $(this).val('REQUIRED');
            $(this).css("background-color","#ffbbbb");
            alert($(this).attr('name') + ' must not be left blank.');
            return false;
        }
    }); // end of the each function
}
</script>
 </head>
 <body>
<form name="queryForm" action="hello.php" onsubmit="return validateForm();" method="post">
<input type="text" name="First Name"><br>
<input type="text" name="Last Name">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
 </body>
</html>
END;
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using return insidw the .each() won't get you the desired result.

Try this:

```
function validateForm() {
alert("Validating");    
var result = true;
   $("form[name=queryForm]").find(":input[type=text]").each(function() {
    alert("Checking " + $(this).attr('name'));
    if($(this).val()==null || $(this).val()=="") {
        $(this).val('REQUIRED');
        $(this).css("background-color","#ffbbbb");
        alert($(this).attr('name') + ' must not be left blank.');
        result =false;
        return false;   //break the each()
    }
}); // end of the each function
return result;
}
```

Comment: Setting a varible and using that as my return outside the 'end' function works.

But why?  

"Using return insidw the .each() won't get you the desired result."  Why not?

Thank you...

Comment: @lowcrawler return inside the each() will call the callback function of each(). Returning false will break the each.

Answer (score 1):

```
find(":input[type=text]")
```

should be

```
find("input[type=text]")
```

Also you might want to return a variable that gets set outside of the `.each`

```
function validateForm() {
    var valid = true;
    alert("Validating");    
    $("form[name=queryForm]").find(":input[type=text]").each(function() {
        alert("Checking " + $(this).attr('name'));
        if($(this).val()==null || $(this).val()=="") {
            $(this).val('REQUIRED');
            $(this).css("background-color","#ffbbbb");
            alert($(this).attr('name') + ' must not be left blank.');
            valid = false;
        }
    }); // end of the each function
    //then return that variable
    return valid;
}
```